# Concerns over making Methods available across multiple forms in c# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know if my approach towards making methods available across multiple forms is safe, or if there are possible issues with my approach that I'm unaware of.

I'm currently working on an application with over a dozen forms and there are certain methods that are called by many of those forms, so instead or recreating them on each form, I created a new class called `Globals.cs` and inside this class I create a series of classes and methods that I call throughout my application.

I haven't noticed any issues with my setup as of yet, but my concern is, what happens if one of my methods inside my Globals.cs would be called simultaneously by different forms? I have void methods that write passed in data to SQL Tables and I have methods that return data.

I use `BackGroundWorkers` in some forms, what would happen if one of these methods was called simultaneously by either two different Workers, or by a Worker and a method call on an other form?

Here is a sample of my Globals.cs class and a few of the methods inside.

```
class Globals
{
    public static string getUserSetting(string userID, string form, string obj_name)
    {
        string value = "";
            // Get setting value from SQL Table and assign it to return variable
        return value;
    }

    public static void saveUserSetting(string userID, string form, string obj_name, string value)
    {
        // Save Passed in settings to SQL Table
    }

    public static string getEnviro()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.EnvironmentDefault))
            return Settings.Default.EnvironmentDefault.ToString();
        else
            return "Live";
    }

    public class Properties
    {
        public static System.Drawing.Color colorPropertyFromString(string stringValue)
        {
            System.Drawing.Color returnValue = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
            {
                int colorIntVal = -1;
                bool output;
                output = int.TryParse(stringValue, out colorIntVal);

                returnValue = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(colorIntVal);
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}


/*
    I use this Class to create new instances of SqlConnections through my application. 
    Example: If I need a new SqlConnection I would go:
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Conn.ConnectionString);
*/
public sealed class Conn
{
    public static string ConnectionString = Settings.Default.ArborgConnectionString.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what standards and naming conventions you're following. It's my recommendation that you rename some of your methods and classes as follows: `GetUserSetting` `SaveUserSetting` `GetEnvironment` `ColorPropertyFromString` `Connection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no general issue with having global methods or properties in a separate class.  This is extremely common.
2. In general you do not need to worry about forms doing two things at once.  Unless you have done something very specific (and difficult), the events (clicks, keypresses, etc) of each form are all handled by a single UI thread across your entire application.  This is true even if you are using the (nasty) [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
3. If you have done the work to separate the UI thread from worker threads (this is common, and is usually a good idea) you can prevent simultaneous access to your global functions by using a simple [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), a slightly more advanced [critical section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx), or by using specific CLR functionality that depends on what you're doing (e.g. you can lock application variables using [Application.Lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525184(v=vs.90).aspx)).
4. Many, many CLR functions are thread safe, and if they are, you can call them without worrying about locking.  Refer to the MSDN documentation for the CLR function; 99% of the time they will tell you whether the function is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, having global function is fine. You need to consider whether it is possible that a function is called simultaneously by more than one thread and whether this could be harmful. Reading a value in one thread while another is updating it is an example. Do some reading on making code thread safe.

Comment: Thank you for the link, what about a method that has input parameters, analyses those parms and returns a result. What happens when a method like this is called simultaneously by more than one thread?  Would thread 2 get the results that thread 1 passed in, or does it create an instance of the method where each thread get's its own results back?

Comment: @Cornelius : If the methods (functions) don't modify any global variables/objects they're fine. A function may be called by any number of simultaneous threads, as the execution of it is done in that specific thread. I guess you could say that it creates an instance of the function, yes.

Comment: You only have to be wary of a resource that you are updating in a method being in an intermediate state when read by one thread because another has not finished updating it. Other than situations like this it is fine for many threads to invoke the same method.

Comment: @Ian and Visual Vincent, So a method or function that writes passed in information to lets say a Sql table would be an issue if it was called simultaneously by different threads?

Comment: In that case you can rely on SQL Server keeping you safe. It can cope with many simultaneous requests.

Comment: I think your concern is misplaced. Your approach of having global functions is the right one. When a thread calls one of them it has its own parameters and local variables. You only have to take precautions if two threads could access the same data,